# How to incrementally update a live-usb?

Tags: 11.04, live-usb

I have created a live usb from an Ubuntu 11.04 daily cd image using usb disk creator. I have bandwidth constrains so I would like to update the live usb from a current daily cd image without downloading an entire image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried two times and it worked for me (But i do not know if this is the correct way to do it). First you need to create the first Live USB following the USB Creator steps.

Then when a new update comes just overwrite the files that are newer than the ones in the usb. Well in my case everything in the dist, pool and casper folder. It worked the two times i have tried but am talking about when 10.10 was in beta till it was released.

Comment: i don't think that this solves bandwith constraints

Answer (score 0):

When you create the USB startup disk, you have the option to partition off so much of the disk into what is known as a persistence file. This file allows you to save your files and settings so that they are available next time you boot up the live image. The option in question can be seen in the below figure as point number 2:

[image]

I haven't tried it myself, but this is how I would go about it.

Comment: Installing upgrades directly from the live usb session fails.

Comment: can you give details exactly why does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

It fails because the file system has been compressed & made read only. When it updates the updates are applied uncompressed, taking up a much larger space. I had 500 MB of updates which took up 4 GB. This is enough to fill a 4 GB casper-rw file.