# Can not update Natty running from a USB stick

Tags: 11.04, usb, live-usb, testing

In [a blogpost](http://www.jonobacon.org/2010/11/30/testing-natty-and-unity-safely-with-a-usb-stick/) Jono explained a nice way to test the latest version of Natty. Under point four he proposes:

> Step 4: Update
>
> Although you installed the latest daily you should ensure it is up to date, and you can do this with:
>
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade

Now, I followed all the steps and am actually writing this question from a session running on a 4GB USB stick. When trying to update the installation though (I just tried to do that using the Update Manager), it always fails because I do not have enough disc space remaining.

How can I get Ubuntu to update properly on my USB stick?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/18403/how-to-incrementally-update-a-live-usb .

Comment: How is this an exact duplicate? I am having different problems. If I understand the second answer correctly then my fault is that I did not reserve enough space using the slider. But then that could be posted here and might help other users straight forwardly as well.

Comment: It gets even funnier, I now used the slider and moved it all the way to the right and it turns out exactly the same problem will occur - with 3GB space. Maybe it is a bug?

Comment: hi ! i got the same problem here . ubuntu 10.10 on usb stick everything fine BUT update always says . "do not have enough disc space remaining" it says i have free 469mb or so but i have a 8GB usb stick :((((( any idea .
thanks ubuntu rules :)

Comment: i got it for my usb stick . I install ubuntu new and  now like ingo gerth used the slider and moved it all the way to the right. and it works . but the install of ubuntu needs now over 15min. and the update about 2hours :) .

Comment: It might be that it's a bug that just requires fixing. In that case, close please!